# Python function returns none after 3 rd use of None

Tags: python, python-2.7

So i was trying to solve some questions and used the given logic for the same.
But even after getting the correct value using print everytime i try to return that value the output is None.

```
def rt(c):
    print "yep",c
    cc(c)
def asa():
        return 3
def klds(s):
    return s+4
def cc(k):
    if k!=7:
        print k
        print 3434   
        return k
    print 2
    rt(k+2)
print cc(klds(asa()))
```

Expected output:
The second last value 3434 is just to check whether function goes after print and 3rd last value is the value to be returned

```
2
yep 9
9
3434
9
```

Getting output:

```
2
yep 9
9
3434
None
```

Comment: `cc()` doesn't return anything when `k` is 7.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`cc` gets called twice here.

`print cc(klds(asa()))`, equivalent to `print cc(7)` is the first time it gets called. Trace it through:

```
if k != 7:  # Nope, keep going...
print 2
rt(k+2)
```

We've hit the end of the function. There is no return statement, so it return `None`, which is what you're seeing at the end.

To fix it, make sure you're returning your values. (i.e. `return rt(k+2)` instead.)

There is a similar problem elsewhere in your code you'll also have to fix before it works like you want it to.

Answer (score 0):

Here's what's happening:

```
print cc(klds(asa()))
```

Starting from the inner-most nested function and working out:

1. asa() returns 3, which is sent to klds().
2. klds() returns s + 4, since asa returns 3, s = 3, so s + 4 == 7
3. We are now inside cc(). Everything inside the 'if' block is skipped, since k == 7
4. 2 is printed, and then rt() is called, given k+2. k still == 7.
5. inside rt(), 'yep', 9 is printed.
6. cc() is called from within rt() with parameter c (c == 9).
7. now in cc() again. Since k == 9, k != 7, so the 'if' block is executed.
8. as you expect, k (which equals 9) and 3434 are printed.
9. the value k is returned.
10. now that a value has been returned, the call to rt() in step 5 has been completed. We can now continue down cc(). However, that was the last line of cc(), and nothing is returned, so None is returned by default
11. your last print statement prints the default None.

Essentially, when you return the value in your if statement, the return sends the value back to the top of the list of executions where it was first invoked. You first invoke this path of executions when you call rt(), so the returned value is returned there. If you want to then return that value, you should assign the thing rt() returns to a variable, and then return that variable